# Remove node from the Corda network

Tags: corda

Currently I have 4 node A, B, C and D with connect to each other in the same Corda Network.

If I want to remove node D from the network, What is the recommended way to do it?

Because now if I stop node D the other node will show that it can't connect to node D.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what network you are using but if..

1. In network bootstrapper you can update each node's network parameter file in corda folder.
2. Testnet I think r3 will not update network map service for you.
3. UAT/Prod net you have to contact r3 for remove unused node, so they'll update network map service and your node will got the new network parameter list.

And make sure that you already change command signer and participant of state that relate to node D because it'll not be able to make transaction again if node D removed.

Hope that help